# creating a bash script to notify alibaba cloud user to change password via email before expiration of 60 days

Tags: bash, cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

Hi i received an error

chage: user 'user' does not exist in /etc/passwd
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Could anyone pls help me to identify my mistake. tq

#!/bin/bash

```
recipient="someane@gmail.com"  # Set the email address of the recipient
subject="Alibaba Cloud Pasword Change Reminder"

 # Check the password expiration date
 expiration_date=$(chage -l user | grep "Password expires" | awk -F ":" '{print $2}')
 expiration_timestamp=$(date -d "$expiration_date" +%s)
 current_timestamp=$(date +%s)
 difference_in_seconds=$((expiration_timestamp-current_timestamp))
 difference_in_days=$((difference_in_seconds/60/60/24))
```

if [ "$difference_in_days" -le 60 ]; then #Send an email if the password will expire within 60 days
message="Hello,

```
This is a reminder to change your Alibaba Cloud account password. It is important to regularly      update your password to ensure the security of your account.

Your password will expire in $difference_in_days days. Please be sure to change it before it expires.

Thank you,
```

Product Team"

```
   echo "$message" | mail -s "$subject" "$recipient"  #Send the email using the mail command
  fi
```

Comment: If you literally using `chage -l user` then you are looking up info for the user `user`.  Expected a variable here. I would use `sed -n '/Password expires/s/.*: //p'` instead of awk.  If you don't know, date can do calculations like `date -d "$expiration_timestamp - 60 days" +%s` which is more readable.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

`chage -l user` is looking up information on the user `user`.  I was expecting a variable for the user name.  Also, you should check if the command is successful:

```
user=...
if ! expires=$(chage -l "$user" | sed -n '/Password expires/s/.*: //p')
then
   // handle error
fi
```